# How to prevent the warning "The template is incompatible with Python3" when deploying a GCP VM with the Bitnami wordpress-multisite?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I am deploying a g1-small instance with the Bitnami Wordpress-Multisite image.
The deployment happens, but with this warning:

> The template is incompatible with Python3. Please fix the following errors: Exception in software_status.py Traceback (most recent call last): return constructor[m]                   (evaluation_context) File "software_status.py", line 188, in GenerateConfig File "software_status.py", line 161, in _Waiter File "software_status.py", line 131, in _WaiterDependsOn AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'StringTypes' Resource: software_status.py Resource: config https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/migrate-to-python3

*Does someone knows how to prevent it?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami developer here.

This is a warning message that Google Marketplace added for validating the deployment templates with Python 3. This is just a warning message and the image will be deployed successfully. Unfortunately there is nothing that you (as user) or Bitnami (as the image provider) can do at this moment. From Bitnami, we already informed Google Marketplace about this error and they are working to address it.

Comment: Just a note to let you know the Google Marketplace team already fixes this issue. The warning message does not appear anymore for new deployments.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly point out, this is a warning about a script that, most likely hasn't been updated to run on python3; since python (2) was deprecated as of January 1, 2020, several scripts seems to be in the process of upgrade (or rework) to make it work flawlessly. At this point, at least in public GIT, it seems that specific script is not been worked in yet but notices here and there (and word from Bitnami's moderator about letting Google team know about this situation) guide us to think this item will be solved, but as this doesn't break the installation (yes, warnings are ugly, but still the job is done) we'll have to endure a little longer while the update progress is done.

Now, to a more TL;DR response: No it cannot be prevented at this time since it would require a rework (code) of that specific script and create an image to deploy, so best bet is to wait for Google's/Botnami's team to finish their process.

Links:

- https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress/issues/199
- https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/migrate-to-python3
- https://community.bitnami.com/t/the-template-is-incompatible-with-python3-please-fix-the-following-errors-exception-in-software-status-py/72377

The other solution, if you require to create a multisite deployment (without Bitami's image) is to create a VM and install LAMP/LNMP stack from ground up and from there create a snapshot, then an image and have it stashed just in case.

I hope this can help you with your issue.